# Highcharts load ajax via Json

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json, highcharts

I can't parse my Json response correctly. Basically I have a function with my highchart:

- I send some post parameters and I get a Json response.
- I use json encode and json headers on my php File.
- I get a Json response.
- I used different ways but I can't parse the json result in order to activate my highcart function.

I'm Getting this:

[image]

My Code:

JS

```
function makeChart2(data) {

$('#container23').highcharts({
    chart: {
        type: 'pie',
        options3d: {
            enabled: true,
            spacingLeft: 0,
            spacingRight: 0,
            alpha: 45
        }
    },
    title: {
        text: "2dfdf"
    },
    subtitle: {
        text: ('Datos Extraídos de las Encuestas')
    },


    plotOptions: {
        pie: {
            innerSize: 100,
            depth: 45,

            dataLabels: {
                format: '<b>{point.name}</b>: {point.percentage:.1f} %',

                enabled: true,
                distance: 45,

            },


        }
    },
    series: [{
        name: 'Respuestas',
        data: data
    }]
});

};

var dataString = '&opper=' + opper + '&sel3=' + valueSelected + '&sel4=' +   nationality;


$.ajax({
type: "POST",
url: "select-ajaxselect3.php",
data: dataString,
cache: false,
async: false,
dataType: "json",
success: function(response) {

    makeChart2(response);
}

});
```

RESPONSE (PHP)

```
"[['er',1],['erer',0],['erer',0],['er',3],['er',0]]"
```

Comment: It should work, what's exactly the problem?

Comment: @MarcoSalerno Edit.

Comment: try to check the series via javascript

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, The `JS` code is fine.

But the `PHP Json` Response not.

We have to ensure Json is valid.

Instead

```
"[['er',1],['erer',0],['erer',0],['er',3],['er',0]]"
```

This

```
"[["er",1],["erer",0],["erer",0],["er",3],["er",0]]"
```

Answer (score 0):

Single Quotes '..' inside JSON is not correct format of JSON

```
"[['er',1],['erer',0],['erer',0],['er',3],['er',0]]"
```

**Your PHP response should be**

```
'[["er",1],["erer",0],["erer",0],["er",3],["er",0]]'
```

If you are getting reponse like this and can't change then you need to replace single quote with double quotes.

```
response = response.replace(/\'/g, '"');
```

Comment: I make the response on Mar 20. Why you are responding this? I said tha same thing in my response.

Comment: Your response is incorrect it's not  "[["er",1],["erer",0],["erer",0],["er",3],["er",0]]" double quote two times will break the string.